# Set / change + add Sinatra views folder

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller, sinatra

I am learning sinatra, and I am trying to create simple website. This is my web directory tree:

```
├── app.rb
│
├── admin
│   └── views
│   └── admin.rb
├── models
├── static
│               
└── views
```

and now I want render views just for admin. In other words: I have 2 views folder in different locations, admin for admin controller and views, and another views is for homepage.

Comment: What have you tried/what isn’t working for you? I don’t see a problem here, just a requirement.

Comment: I tried to `load 'admin/admin.rb'` , and the result is not render **views** in the folder `admin` but render `views` in `root` folder. I try to set views folder into admin folder it's works just for admin. Not for homepage, I am new in programming specially ruby/sinatra. I don't know how to load different views.

Comment: Post the relevant code you’re currently using to set/change the views folder.

Comment: I already change the subject.. :)

Comment: why don't you do `views/admin`? Sinatra == simplicity. You're breaking the concept :)

Comment: I already do that, but I just want to read directory more simple,,hhe.

Answer (score 2):

Add config.ru file in root application  folder

```
require './app'
require './admin/admin'
# run MyApp
run Rack::URLMap.new("/" => MyApp.new, "/admin" => AdminApp.new)
```

In app.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  get "/app" do
    haml :app
  end
end
```

In admin.rb

```
# admin.rb
class AdminApp < Sinatra::Base
  get "/" do
    haml :index
  end
end
```

Finally in console `rackup -p PORTNUMBER` example

```
rackup -p 4000
```

**Update**

Reference to [Gist](https://gist.github.com/4618134)

Comment: You could wrap Db relate conf in a Model Class, like `database.rb` (create folder for config) and load the config in class using config file or read configs from ENV. Then, share it between different Route files. And, of course you would have to load it up in the route.

Comment: sorry for previous comment I was deleted. I already done wiht it.. :) . Excellence, :) . thanks for your help. it works..